# Wordpress plugin Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

I'm getting this error when attempting to update code for my wordpress site:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

I've found the line it is referring to and cannot find the error...

```
<input type="submit" name="cmdSubmit" value="' . __( 'ADD/UPDATE', 'wp-fevents-book' ) . '" style="background-color:' . $evento['Colore'] . '; color: #0d1764;" />';
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you post 2 or 3 lines above and below that one?

Comment: This line does not appear to be complete: you have a terminating semicolon but no variable declaration, etc. Did you cut off part of the line of code?

Comment: sentence has not echo at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From above information whatever you are provided

```
 echo  '<input type="submit" name="cmdSubmit" value="' . __( 'ADD/UPDATE', 'wp-fevents-book' ) . '" style="background-color:' . $evento['Colore'] . '; color: #0d1764;" />';
```